# Predicting an inequality, given $f''(x)<0$ in $[a,b].$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We are given that a function $f(x)$ is twice differentiable in $[a,b]$ and $f''(x)<0$.

Let $c=(a+b)/2.$ The question: Is $f(c)$ is greater than or less than $$\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}?$$

Now I realized that there is some $c$ in $[a,b]$ for which $f(c)=\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$ by intermediate value theorem.

After this I thought that since $f''(x)<0$ so $f'(x)$ is decreasing in $[a,b]$. Now I took two cases:

1. If $f(x)$ is increasing ie. $f'(x)>0$ so this means that the rate of increase lessens as we move towards $b$ from $a$ so the difference in values of $f(c)-f(a)>f(b)-f(c)$ which gives $2f(c)>f(a)+f(b)$.
2. If $f(x)$ is decreasing ie. $f'(x)<0$ so this means that the rate of decrease lessens as we move towards $b$ from $a$ so the difference in values of $f(a)-f(c)>f(c)-f(b)$ which gives $2f(c)<f(a)+f(b)$.

Now I am confused as both yield opposite results. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign of $f'$ does not matter, only that – as you correctly observed – $f'$ is decreasing. Formally this can be  shown by repeated application of the mean-value theorem:
$$
 f(c)-f(a) = (c-a) f'(d_1) \quad \text{ for some $d_1$ between $a$ and $c$ } \\
 f(b)-f(c) = (b-c) f'(d_2) \quad \text{ for some $d_2$ between $c$ and $b$ }
$$
and therefore 
$$
 f(a)+f(b) - 2f(c) = \frac{a+b}{2} (f'(d_2)-f'(d_1)) \\
=  \frac{a+b}{2}  (d_2-d_1) f''(e) \quad \text{ for some $e$ between $d_1$ and $d_2$ } 
$$
and that is negative, i.e. $f(c) > \frac 12 (f(a) + f(b))$.

More generally, a twice differentiable function is (strictly) *concave* exactly if $f''$ is (strictly) negative.

Comment: But I still don't get what goes wrong when you assume signs for $f'(x)$?

Comment: You can not assume $f$ is either increasing or decreasing on $(a,b)$. It may have local min(s) or max(s) on $(a,b).$

Comment: @infinite-blank-: What you wrote in (2) is wrong: Even if $f'$ is negative: $f'$ decreases with increasing $x$.

Comment: @MartinR Ok I get it now thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $g( x)=f(x)-l(x)$ where $l(x)$ is the straight line segment connecting the points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$

Note that $g''( x)=f''(x)>0$ and $g(a)=g(b)=0$

From the second derivative sign of $g(x) $ we realize that $g(x)$ is concave down on $[a,b]$ so $g(\frac {a+b}{2})>0$

That implies $$f(\frac {a+b}{2})>\frac {f(a)+f(b)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is concave on $[a,b]$ so the line segment $\vec {PQ}$ where $P=(a,f(a)),\ Q=(b,f(b))$ lies below the graph of $f$. Also, $f$ achieves it minimum $m$ and maximum $M$ on $[a,b]$ But now, since $m\le \frac{f(b)+f(a)}{2}\le M$, the result follows by the intermediate value theorem.